# Why this recursive function doesn't break?

Tags: python

### Short version:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import re
import itertools

targ = ['\t- Task 09', '\tThis is a comment', '\t\t- Subtask 9.02', '\t\t\t- Subsubtask 9.03', '\t\t\t\t- Subsubsubtask 9.01 @done', '\t\t\t\t- Subsubsubtask 9.02', '\t\t\t\t\t- Subsubsubsubtask 9.01 @done', '\t\t\t\t- Subsubsubtask 9.03 @done', '\t\t\t- Subsubtask 9.04', '\t\t\t\t- Subsubsubtask 9.19 @done']


def DoneChild2Parent(l):
    tasks = [(k,v) for k,v in enumerate(l) if re.search('\t+-\s.*',v)]
    for x,y in tasks:       
        if (x,y) == tasks[len(tasks[1:])]:
            print (x,y), '==', tasks[len(tasks[1:])]
            return l #Also tried break here.
        elif re.search('(?!.*@done)\t*-\s.*', y):
            next_task = tasks[tasks.index((x,y))+1]
            if next_task[1].count('\t') > y.count('\t'):
                subtasks = list(itertools.takewhile(lambda t: t.count('\t') > y.count('\t'), [z for w,z in tasks[tasks.index(next_task):]]))
                if all('@done' in subtask for subtask in subtasks):
                    l[x]+=' @done'
                    DoneChild2Parent(l)
    # return l #when using break above
print DoneChild2Parent(targ)
```

This function should return when matching the latest element of the list. Right now it just keeps looping. It identifies when `(x,y) == tasks[len(tasks[1:])]:`, but neither return nor break take me out of the loop.

---

### After Comments:

This is a more reduced version of the code. I reduced the argument to as small as possible while keeping the problem:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import re

targ = ['\t- Task 09', '\tThis is a comment', '\t\t- Subtask 9.02', '\t\t\t- Subsubtask 9.03', '\t\t\t\t- Subsubsubtask 9.01 @done', '\t\t\t\t- Subsubsubtask 9.02', '\t\t\t\t\t- Subsubsubsubtask 9.01 @done', '\t\t\t\t- Subsubsubtask 9.03 @done', '\t\t\t- Subsubtask 9.04', '\t\t\t\t- Subsubsubtask 9.19 @done']


def DoneChild2Parent(l):
    tasks = iter([(x,y) for x,y in enumerate(l) if re.search('\t+-\s.*',y)])

    for k in tasks:
        if re.search('(?!.*@done)\t*-\s.*', k[1]):
            nt = tasks.next()
            if nt[1].count('\t') > k[1].count('\t'):
                subtasks = [subtask for subtask in l[k[0]:] if subtask.count('\t') > k[1].count('\t') and re.search('\t+-\s.*',subtask) ]
                if all('@done' in subtask for subtask in subtasks):
                    l[k[0]]+=' @done'
                    DoneChild2Parent(l)
    return l

print DoneChild2Parent(targ)
```

Concerning @abarnert questions: I need the "next task" to compare the amount of '\t' between it and the task in question. If the *next task* has more '\t' than *task*, means *next task* is a subtask of *task*. If all children of *task* are marked with "@done" it should also mark *task*. I filter the whole input to avoid comments (according to the syntax), which would break the code. I also keep the index from the original list to add the '@done' tag afterwards. I hope this code runs smoother to all of you. Thank you for the kindness of passing by and reading this wall of text (:

---

#### A different version of the code with the same problem:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import re
import itertools

targ = ['\t- Task 09', '\tThis is a comment', '\t\t- Subtask 9.02', '\t\t\t- Subsubtask 9.03', '\t\t\t\t- Subsubsubtask 9.01 @done', '\t\t\t\t- Subsubsubtask 9.02', '\t\t\t\t\t- Subsubsubsubtask 9.01 @done', '\t\t\t\t- Subsubsubtask 9.03 @done', '\t\t\t- Subsubtask 9.04', '\t\t\t\t- Subsubsubtask 9.19 @done']


def DoneChild2Parent(l):
    tasks = [(k,v) for k,v in enumerate(l) if re.search('\t+-\s.*',v)]
    for x,y in tasks[:-1]:
        if re.search('(?!.*@done)\t*-\s.*', y):
            next_task = tasks[tasks.index((x,y))+1]
            if next_task[1].count('\t') > y.count('\t'):
                subtasks = list(itertools.takewhile(lambda t: t.count('\t') > y.count('\t'), [z for w,z in tasks[tasks.index(next_task):]]))
                if all('@done' in subtask for subtask in subtasks):
                    l[x]+=' @done'
                    DoneChild2Parent(l)
    return l

print DoneChild2Parent(targ)
```

---

### Really long explanation with original code:

Apologies for the open title and above all for asking you to identify a problem instead of only suggesting a solution to an issue already found. The code below is the reduced version of the code I'm using, I removed a few useless functions, but the outcome is just the same. The printed result on the console will guide us through my problem:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import re
import itertools

targ = '\t- Task 09\n\tThis is a comment\n\t\t- Subtask 9.01 @done\n\t\tThis is a subtask comment\n\t\t- Subtask 9.02\n\t\tAnother comment\n\t\t\t- Subsubtask 9.01 @done\n\t\t\t- Subsubtask 9.02 @done\n\t\t\tWhy so many comments?\n\t\t\t- Subsubtask 9.03\n\t\t\t\t- Subsubsubtask 9.01 @done\n\t\t\t\tJust another comment to break your code\n\t\t\t\t- Subsubsubtask 9.02\n\t\t\t\tBreak, break, break\n\t\t\t\t\t- Subsubsubsubtask 9.01 @done\n\t\t\t\t\tThis is the last comment, I promise\n\t\t\t\t- Subsubsubtask 9.03 @done\n\t\t\t\tI lied.\n\t\t\t- This is the task of interest\n\t\t\t\t- Subsubsubtask 9.03 @done\n\t\t\t\tI love lying\n\t\t\t- Subsubtask 9.05 @done\n\t\t- Subtask 9.03 @done\n\t\tOk, this is truly the last comment.\n\t\tNah.'

regex =  re.split('\n(?=^\t-\s)', targ, 0, re.M)

c = 0
def DoneChild2Parent(l):
    global c
    c+=1
    tasks = iter([(x,y) for x,y in enumerate(l) if re.search('\t+-\s.*',y)])
    
    print "=================\n==:: ROUND %s ::==\n================="%(c)
    
    for k in tasks:
        print "* Step 1: %s => This is the task being checked:" %(str(k))
        if re.search('(?!.*@done)\t*-\s.*', k[1]):
            print "* Step 2: %s => Was not done so we check the next task/subtasks" %(str(k))
            nt = tasks.next()
            if nt[1].count('\t') > k[1].count('\t'):
                print "* Step 3: %s => is the next subtask" %(str(nt))
                subtasks = [subtask for subtask in l[k[0]:] if subtask.count('\t') > k[1].count('\t') and re.search('\t+-\s.*',subtask) ]
                print "* Length of subtasks is",len(subtasks)
                print "* Step 4: Subtasks for %s\n" %(k[0]),subtasks
                if all('@done' in subtask for subtask in subtasks):
                    print "\n* Step 5: Adding @done to %s at index %s" %(k[1].strip(), k[0])
                    print "Before: ",l[k[0]]
                    l[k[0]]+=' @done'
                    print "After: ",l[k[0]],"\n---------------------\n"
                    DoneChild2Parent(l)
                else:
                    print "\n* Step 5: Not everything is done yet\n---------------------\n"
                    
    return l

for task in regex:
    itask = task.split('\n')
    DoneChild2Parent(itask)
```

The string is a task list using the syntax from TaskPaper, a task manager for Mac that uses plain text files. A task starts with '- ', a project ends with ':'(absent in this example), a comment is neither. Indentation defines hierarchy between tasks and comments. When a task is marked as done, it gains a tag '@done' (every tag starts with @). For this example I'm using a single, multi-layered task. The regex and the for-loop in the end are there in case of multiple main-tasks (when the project is the direct parent).

The function loops through every task from the list, checks if it is undone and contains subtasks. Afterwards, it collects all its subtasks and checks if they're all marked as @done, if so, it marks the parent-task as @done as well.

When you run this script, you'll find out that the purpose works, but the loop proceeds for more than intended and takes a weird direction. I named the task where the problem occurs as 'This is the task of interest' so you can easily spot it on print.

The task of interest is correctly marked as @done in the Round 3 of the script. The script continues to loop until it marks the main-task in Round 5, meaning that every subtask is marked as @done (the list was built with that in mind). Now, please, take a good look at Round 6. It was supposed to be the latest loop, where the function would check that there's nothing left to do and return the value, however, as you may notice by the following lines:

```
* Step 1: (22, '\t\t- Subtask 9.03 @done') => This is the task being checked:
* Step 1: (4, '\t\t- Subtask 9.02 @done') => This is the task being checked:
```

It checks the last task and loops back to the start. I don't know why it loops back at the second task. This behaviour repeats and the task that begins the re-loop is always different. I'd like to know why that happens. But worst, you'll notice that at a given moment the script finds the 'Task of interest', the one we marked as @done before, undone and operates the loop again. The result is that the 'Task of interest' ends up with 3 @done tags attached to it:

```
After:              - This is the task of interest @done @done @done
```

The outcome I'm looking for is Round 8 at Round 6. Thank you for your attention and I'm sorry for such a long text.

Comment: That's an awful lot of code, still. If I'm feeling energetic, I may come back and look later, but it is not easy reading, for all you say you've reduced it.  One way you could simplify the code is by simply creating what you currently call `regex` as a simple list of strings: `list = ['string1', 'string2', 'string3'…]`.

Comment: I agree with @JonathanLeffler - this is too much code.

You seem to be making the assumption that SO users will run your code - it's simply not the case. 

Try and write your samples such that it's readable without opening up a new instance of our IDE.

Comment: Besides being too much code, it's also over-complicated in many ways. For example, it looks like you're doing a `next(tasks)` inside a `for k in tasks` just as a way to avoid using `continue`. And it's only because you wanted to do that that you've had to wrap your iterable in `iter` instead of just iterating it directly. (Also, why do you _want_ to skip over the next task in this case? Is there a reason you want to test tasks 0, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 19, 21, and 22? If so, can you explain that reason?)

Comment: Also, it's way too much _data_. Can't you come up with an example that doesn't have 8 rounds of multiple steps of 22 values where we have to look somewhere about two thirds of the way through hundreds of lines of output to even see what the problem is?

Comment: Hello! I edited the description, there's a section named **After Comments** with a smaller code and a few questions answered. I hope it helps. I also included another version of the code that also generates the same issue.

Worth remembering that the issue is extra loops which add extra '@done' to one of the tasks, 'Subsubtask 9.04'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your help. [This StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12191812/how-do-i-break-out-of-this-recursive-loop) helped me a lot. I just had to place a `break` in the right place:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import re
import itertools

targ = ['\t- Task 09', '\tThis is a comment', '\t\t- Subtask 9.02', '\t\t\t- Subsubtask 9.03', '\t\t\t\t- Subsubsubtask 9.01 @done', '\t\t\t\t- Subsubsubtask 9.02', '\t\t\t\t\t- Subsubsubsubtask 9.01 @done', '\t\t\t\t- Subsubsubtask 9.03 @done', '\t\t\t- Subsubtask 9.04', '\t\t\t\t- Subsubsubtask 9.19 @done']


def DoneChild2Parent(l):
    tasks = [(k,v) for k,v in enumerate(l) if re.search('\t+-\s.*',v)]
    for x,y in tasks:       
        if re.search('(?!.*@done)\t*-\s.*', y):
            next_task = tasks[tasks.index((x,y))+1]
            if next_task[1].count('\t') > y.count('\t'):
                subtasks = list(itertools.takewhile(lambda t: t.count('\t') > y.count('\t'), [z for w,z in tasks[tasks.index(next_task):]]))
                if all('@done' in subtask for subtask in subtasks):
                    l[x]+=' @done'
                    DoneChild2Parent(l)
                    break
    return l

print DoneChild2Parent(targ)
```

Why this happened? Simple, the loop would call the function, but it wouldn't end. So when the last-loop called no function and concluded, it would return the result to the previous function and proceed with the loop, which would find other issues already fixed in previous tasks and call the function again, generating the mess you saw (:

Answer (score 1):

I'd start by asking exactly what you hope this regexp matches:

```
if re.search('(?!.*@done)\t*-\s.*', k[1]):
```

Explain your intent in words?  Are you, for example, surprised that it matches this string:

```
"abc @done- def"
```

?  Do you realize that the trailing `.*` in that regexp serves no purpose (the regexp matches exactly the same strings with and without it)?

I don't know whether it's related to your problem ;-), but I've seen a lot of regexps in my life, and I can't guess what you hoped this one would do.  My best guess is that you hope it matches `\t*-\s` not immediately preceded by `@done` - but in that case you want a negative look*behind* assertion instead.

Comment: Hello, Tim. I created this regexp using Patterns to match solely tasks (preceded by \t-\s) that do not contain @done. The output seems correct according to the application.

Comment: And I'm not surprised it matches that string, although I should avoid matching '@done-'. Will work on that, although it is not related to the issue, I'm afraid.